# How to change the underline thickness in react native

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, stylesheet

I have been using reactive native for a few weeks and I have stuck at a point. I have a text and it is underlined. But I need to make the thickness of the underline higher so that it is clearly visible. I tried finding a solution and didn't get any. Can someone help me here?

My code is like the following. :

```js
<Text style={{textDecorationLine: 'underline'}}>Underlined Text</Text>
```

Comment: AFAIK, you can't change the width of the underline, my best idea would be to use wrap the text with a view with `borderBottom` instead. You'll probably have to provide a `lineHeight` prop in the text too.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextInput style={styles.textInput}/>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
  textInput: {

    borderBottomColor: '#000', // Add this to specify bottom border color
    borderBottomWidth:  10   // Add this to specify bottom border thickness
}
});
```

Comment: I tried using this in my ```selected``` styles such that when I click on the text, it gets underlined. I wanted to increase the width of the underline so tried using borderBottom instead of underline but it doesn't work for me. Could you take a look? https://snack.expo.io/@saachitech/da6280

Answer (score 0):

Underline Text

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create(
{
  Container:  
  {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex: 1,
  },
  TextStyle: 
  {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 20,
    textDecorationLine: 'underline',
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the thickness of the underline isn't customizable, BUT we can work around using border, length of the border can be adjusted by wrapping the text by a view and use `flexwrap`

```
<View style={styles.titleContainer}>
    <Text style={styles.titles} >Some Text</Text>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  titleContainer: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
  titles: {
    fontWeight: "800",
    borderBottomColor: '#ffffff',
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    paddingBottom: 8,
    paddingHorizontal: 5,
  },
})
```

you will have something like this
[image]